# fancybox close button looks different on some cell phones

Tags: css, responsive-design, fancybox-2

i've ben developing a responsive website which works great on most of cell phones but i have a problem which is the look of the fancybox close button on samsung galaxy s3 and 4. below is a photo containing 2 screenshots the top is from most of the cell phones and the second is from galaxy s3  http://s1.postimg.org/hrbpjx7vz/10589872_726293287427102_258568412_n.jpg

and here's the css code

```
background: url(../images/close0.png) !important;
width: 43px !important;
height: 43px !important;
border: 1px solid #ed1c24 !important;
border-radius: 50% !important;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the background-size attribute, try adding to the CSS...

```
 background-size:43px 43px; //or whatever the size of the bg image
 zoom:1;
```